# JavaScript is not waiting for Async Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I currently have the problem that my JS is reaching the end of my functions before all database calls have fulfilled. Which causes my function to return an incomplete dataset.

I've now tried async/await and Promise.then(). Now i'm mixing both but i don't get my function to wait until everything is done.

That's my code:

```
async function fillData(dashboards) {
  let mapDashboards = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    dashboards.map(async (dashboard) => {
      if (dashboard.widgets) {
        await dashboard.widgets.map(async (widget) => {
          if (widget.panels) {
            await widget.panels.map(async (panel) => {
              if (panel.tabs) {
                await mapPanelTabs(panel).then((tabs) => (panel.tabs = tabs));
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(dashboards);
    resolve(dashboards);
  });

  return mapDashboards;
}

function mapPanelTabs(panel) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (panel.tabs) {
      var tabs = [];
      panel.tabs.forEach(async (tab, index) => {
        const dbTab = await Tab.findById(tab.id)
          .clone()
          .catch((e) => console.log(e));
        if (dbTab) {
          console.log("dbtab found");
          tab = {};
          if (dbTab.queryData && dbTab.queryData.id) {
            await dataController
              .findById(dbTab.queryData.id)
              .catch((e) => console.log(e))
              .then((queryData) => {
                if (dbTab.type === "chart") {
                  // Some more logic
                tabs[index] = tab;
              });
          }
        } else {
          tabs[index] = null;
        }
      });
      resolve(tabs);
    }
  });
}
```

I need to get the promise in `fillData` to wait with the resolve until `mapPanelTabs` is done with the mapping.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not returning anything from these `map`s so there is nothing to await for.

Comment: None of the maps are returning anything

Comment: @nicholaswmin your answer did indeed help. I've now got the promise to wait for the rest to complete. But now i've got the problem that the object I tried to write to seems to be read only.